# Which lightweight Terminal Emulators supports Transparency?

Tags: software-recommendation, command-line, gnome-terminal, transparency, xterm

I know that gnome-terminal and the kde terminal both support transparency, but I'm looking for something lighter on resources than those. What other xterminal emulators support transparency?

Answer (score 3):

Guake Terminal may work for you

```
sudo apt-get install guake
```

- http://www.guake.org

Comment: I don't know how lightweight it is compared to the others, but I recently discovered Guake and like it a lot.

Comment: One voteup for guake! :) Really a light weight emulator program. Call it using a configurable hotkey. Tab support is fine.

Comment: Guake is cool, but it gets confused by dual-monitor setups. I run Ubuntu off a laptop to the left of my primary monitor, and after configuring some settings in Guake and pressing F12, it showed up on the laptop monitor. And there it stayed on each subsequent invocation.

Answer (score -1):

xfce4-terminal and eterm also support transparency (although eterm is just pseudo-transparency IIRC).

Answer (score -1):

[Tilda](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tilda/) is similar to guake.  I use it with the F12 hotkey, so my terminal is open anytime I want.

Only issue with both Guake and Tilda, if you set the transparency option on and have it run at bootup, the transparency won't work.  You'll have to manually activate it on boot.

Comment: I don't have that problem with Guake (0.4.2) at all.  It always stays the same level.

Comment: Really?  Happens with me all the time on my Asus with both 10.10 and 12.04.  I'm thinking it might be a hardware issue or something?

Comment: I doubt it, but anything's possible.  Do you use gnome?  The setting is saved in gconf, under `apps/guake/style/background`.  I don't know what might happen if you aren't using gnome.  Also, if it matters, I'm using 11.10, gnome classic mode with compiz.  Haven't tried it with Unity, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score -1):

My personal favorite is `terminator` which supports true transparency:

```
sudo apt-get install terminator
```

For seriously lightweight and transparency (not true transparency, it will show your desktop background), try `aterm`:

```
sudo apt-get install aterm
```